# Insert value based on other value of same table

Tags: sql, oracle

lets assume I have a table like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 120 |  |
| 90 |  |
| 60 |  |
| 150 |  |

Now I want to fill the empty column B with string values somehow like this:

if column A > 100: insert "high number"
else: insert "low number"

So that: 120 -> high number, 90 -> low number, etc...

How would I do that in Oracle SQL?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try using a CASE statement

Comment: Hint : **Virtual columns**

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `UPDATE` statement with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET column_b = CASE
               WHEN column_a > 100
               THEN 'high number'
               ELSE 'low number'
               END;
```

However, it would be better, to make `column_b` a virtual column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  column_a NUMBER,
  column_b VARCHAR2(11) 
           GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
             CASE 
             WHEN column_a > 100
             THEN 'high number'
             ELSE 'low number'
             END
           )
);
```

Then if the `column_a` value changes the `column_b` value will stay in sync with it.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8398MVIW)